# Java fast build cycle ( Tomcat + Maven + Vagrant )

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

**Scenario**:

Vagrant has Tomcat and Database + other third party stuff.

Host has a synced folder with vagrant containing one/several java web applications.

**Question**:

Since both guest and host contain the same code, is there any "hot deploy" into Tomcat without making a war file ? ( oh boy, I miss hitting save and getting changes... )

My attempts so far were `war:inplace`, and hotswapping with IDE Debugger, both don't cover something like changing method signature.

I've read somewhere about symlinking the target directly into webapps, but Tomcat doesn't pick my changes, might be missing some configuration...

Comment: Is this question for personal or professional purposes? If the latter, JRocket can often make the swap where the IDE may fail.

Comment: JRebel can do this too